# How to communicate between other.js and background.js in electron + vue

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex

I'm making an app with electron + vue + vuex 
I would like to do when action triggered in store.js also trigger to background.js
such as open new window or close it.

I think ipc is best deal but an error comes out when I use it in store.js

---

Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: electron__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.send is not a function
    at Store.remove (webpack:///./src/store.js?:169:57)

---

after refresh app it works without error probably ipcRendere is not imported in store.js at the first time.

ipc works only between Vue and background.js

Is there a way to make it work naturally between store.js and background.js ?

store.js

```
import ipcRenderer from 'electron'

export default new Vuex.Store({
....
mutations: {
  remove (state, code) {
      if (state.gSettings.goWidget) {
        // remove WidgetWin
        ipcRenderer.send('test') // send is not a function error comes out
      }
    },
...
```

background.js

```
...

ipcMain.on('test', (event, arg) => {
  console.log('test')
})
```

Comment: You should not communicate directly between the store and a renderer but only between a renderer and the main process. If you need to communicate between renderers you have to relay IPC messages via the main process.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I slowly change my code not to use ipc in store. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:
`import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron';`
instead of
`import ipcRenderer from 'electron';`

You can read more about `default export` vs `export`.

Comment: @user1911959 Another problem is you don't have access to ipcRenderer in client side. You'll need to use `remote` module. See here https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3386#issuecomment-155454390